# APIM Response Headers Different Between Azure Portal, Developer Portal and Postman

Tags: azure, http, postman, azure-api-management

I am learning Azure API Management and am seeing different response headers between Azure Portal, Developer Portal and Postman.

I'm doing an HTTP Get on this endpoint:
https://secondattempt.azure-api.net/speakers

With https://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net/ as the web service URL.

I have compared them here:

**Azure Portal:**

1. Cache-Control
2. Pragma
3. Transfer-Encoding
4. Content-Type
5. Expires
6. Set-Cookie **(not present)**
7. Date
8. Op-Apim-Trace-Location
9. Vary

**Developer Portal:**

1. Cache-Control
2. Pragma
3. Transfer-Encoding
4. Content-Type
5. Expires
6. Set-Cookie
7. Date
8. Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location
9. Vary **(not present)**

**Postman:**

1. Cache-Control
2. Pragma
3. Transfer-Encoding
4. Content-Type
5. Expires
6. Set-Cookie
7. Date
8. Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location **(not present)**
9. Vary **(not present)**

And here are what they actually look like in the UI:

**Azure Portal:**
[image: Azure Portal]

**Developer Portal:**
[image: Developer Portal]

**Postman:**
[image: Postman]

Why are some headers present in some environments but not others?

Also, why are the headers appearing in different orders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For Postman (Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location not present)

   The OCP-Apim-Trace feature enables you to specify whether or not APIM should generate a trace file on blob storage.

   While doing a GET request from Postman, OCP-Apim-Trace is not enabled.

   Setting the header to 'true' within Postman, for example, will give you back an HTTP Header in the response called OCP-Apim-Trace-Location.

   This will contain the URL to your trace file, which you can open in any browser.
2. For Postman and Developer portal (Vary not resent)

   A request is not cached. Each request for a URL is supposed to be treated as a  unique and uncacheable request.
3. For Azure Portal ( Set-Cookie not present)

   See Trace and then forward request we do see "name": "Set-Cookie", "value": "ARRAffinity

[image]